# Error after adding Razor page using Entity Framework (CRUD). The namespace already contains that definition and Ambiguity between models

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am new in web developing. Was writing an **ASP.NET Core** project through a PluralSight [tutorial](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/aspnet-core-fundamentals/table-of-contents).

I had a list of restaurants using SqlServer, with usual operations like delete, edit, etc. But when I used **Razor page using Entity Framework (CRUD)** and scaffolded those pages, It shows some errors when I want to build the project.

[Screen shot of solution explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5qNk.jpg)

It worked fine until I created that scaffolded pages in the R2 folder and got several errors. All of them was like these two:

> Error CS0101  The namespace 'OdeToFood' already contains a definition for 'DeleteModel'
>
> Error CS0229  Ambiguity between 'DeleteModel.Restaurant' and 'DeleteModel.Restaurant'

[Screen shot of Error list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDeZK.jpg)

I tried another similar project I have and it threw similar errors too.
I also spend time to google it and read some questions here. But couldn't find a really similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used different namespaces and it solved the problem.

I tried to change "namespace" names in the new version of Razor Pages (That were scaffolded by Razor page using Entity Framework (CRUD)). And the errors are gone.

For example, I changed the namespace "OdeToFood" in Delete.cshtmll.cs from "OdeToFood" to:

```
namespace OdeToFood.Pages.R2
    {
        .....
    }
```

Then, in its razor page, Delete.cshtml, I used the new namespace :

```
@model OdeToFood.Pages.R2.DeleteModel
```